# Cursor Exception during Async Task

Tags: android, json, sqlite, cursor

I am running a background task that goes out and downloads a JSON file, pareses it, then adds it to the contents to a SQLite database.

I am getting a couple of errors when it runs.

> Caused by: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor
>   window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=728 (# cursors
>   opened by this proc=728)
>
> E/CursorWindow: Could not allocate CursorWindow
>   '/data/data/com.mycompany.inventory/databases/dbInventory.sql' of size
>   2097152 due to error -12.

The JSON has about 1500 items in it.

Here is the method my async task calls:

```
public void addModelsToDB(JSONObject dict){
        String  insertQuery  = "";
        String  deleteQuery  = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'tblModels'";
        String  createQuery  = "CREATE TABLE 'tblModels' ('modelsID' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,'makeKey' INTEGER, 'modelName' TEXT, 'modelKey' INTEGER)";

        Cursor cursor = dbLocals.executeRawQuery(deleteQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cursor = dbLocals.executeRawQuery(createQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        try {
            JSONArray dicRecordSet  = dict.getJSONArray("Recordset");
            JSONObject dicRecords = dicRecordSet.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONArray arrRecords = dicRecords.getJSONArray("Record");


            for (int i = 0; i < arrRecords.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject record = arrRecords.getJSONObject(i);
                insertQuery = "INSERT INTO 'tblModels' VALUES(" + null +  ", "
                        + record.getString("MODMAKlMakeKey") + ", '"
                        + record.getString("MODvc50Name").replaceAll("'", "''") + "', "
                        + record.getString("MODlModelKey")
                        +")";
                cursor =  dbLocals.executeRawQuery(insertQuery, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
```

**My database a manager returns a cursor.**

```
public Cursor executeRawQuery(String query, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = databaseConn.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
        return cursor;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse the cursor variable because it shadows the original one, and therefore you can't close it:

```
Cursor cursor = dbLocals.executeRawQuery(deleteQuery, null);
```

then

```
cursor =  dbLocals.executeRawQuery(insertQuery, null);
```

this second assignment means you can't close the original cursor.

Also, why are you creating the table here?

Edit:

Use it like this:

```
public void addModelsToDB(JSONObject dict){
    String  insertQuery  = "";
    String  deleteQuery  = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'tblModels'";
    String  createQuery  = "CREATE TABLE 'tblModels' ('modelsID' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,'makeKey' INTEGER, 'modelName' TEXT, 'modelKey' INTEGER)";

    Cursor cursor = dbLocals.executeRawQuery(deleteQuery, null);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cursor = dbLocals.executeRawQuery(createQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    try {
        JSONArray dicRecordSet  = dict.getJSONArray("Recordset");
        JSONObject dicRecords = dicRecordSet.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray arrRecords = dicRecords.getJSONArray("Record");


        for (int i = 0; i < arrRecords.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject record = arrRecords.getJSONObject(i);
            insertQuery = "INSERT INTO 'tblModels' VALUES(" + null +  ", "
                    + record.getString("MODMAKlMakeKey") + ", '"
                    + record.getString("MODvc50Name").replaceAll("'", "''") + "', "
                    + record.getString("MODlModelKey")
                    +")";
            cursor =  dbLocals.executeRawQuery(insertQuery, null);
            try {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. thanks for the pointer. Every so often I need to clear out the local db and start fresh, I find it easier to drop the table. Should I do it another way?

Comment: I would do a delete, but dropping the table works too. Just curious why you were doing it here.

Comment: Are you saying to close the cursor after the delete query. Instantiate a new Cursor for insertQuery and then close it?

Comment: Yes, after dropping the table close that cursor. Afterwards you can reuse the variable "cursor".

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Answer (score -1):

You should close cursors after using them. Inside the loop, you are creating a cursor every iteration, without ever closing it. Apparently there is a limit for the number of open cursors and you hit that limit.

Comment: Am I not doing that? I am calling cursor.close();

Comment: That is the last one you used, what about the previous ones that you lose reference to in the loop?